# How to turn off Nifi Processor Schedule

Tags: apache-nifi

I have GetHttp and InvokeHttp Nifi processors which initiates flows in Nifi, but I want them to get from the URLs only once and pass the data to the next process  With processor configurations I am unable to turn off scheduling, how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InvokeHttp` could be not initial and could be triggered by incoming flow file from other processor.

So, you can put kind of sync logic before and after  your `InvokeHTTP` processor.

For example you can use `Wait`/`Notify` processors.

Answer (score 8):

Apache NiFi processors and flows are designed for constant data streams rather than single "job executions" or "batch processing". A metaphor we use often is that rather than building and fitting pipes to run water through, NiFi helps you dig irrigation ditches along an already-flowing river. The data is already there (and moving) all the time.

If this is truly a one-time action you need to trigger, you can set the *Run Schedule* to something like `30 sec` and manually *Start* and then *Stop* those processors. They will execute once, and as long as you stop them within 30 seconds, not execute again.

If this isn't something you can do manually, you can set the *Run Schedule* to something like `52 weeks`. You can also change the *Scheduling Strategy* to `CRON driven` and set the *Run Schedule* to a crontab parameter with a very long schedule.

As @daggett noted, you can also use the `Wait`/`Notify` processors to trigger a flow which otherwise would not execute, but this only works for `InvokeHTTP`, as `GetHTTP` is a *source* processor.