# Apache NiFi: programmatically stop the Custom Processor

Tags: java, etl, apache-nifi

I'm programming of custom NiFi Processor which extends  `org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor`

I don't want the processor to repeat the same iteration, so how to programmatically stop the processor after transfer the FlowFile to the appropriate destination processor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There currently isn't a way for a processor to stop itself. Processors are meant to be continuously running and triggered based on their scheduling strategy, or the presence of data in a queue leading in to a processor.

Andy explained this well in a question yesterday:

[How to turn off Nifi Processor Schedule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153120/how-to-turn-off-nifi-processor-schedule)